# Codeigniter order by price ranking

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to rank the price of products in the database from low to high, but something seems to have gone wrong. How can I handle this problem?

**I have a price table as follows. sample table**

```
ID || kitap_id || Title || bot_fiyat
1       - 1  -   Title 1  - 4,90
2       - 1  -   Title 2  - 8,20
3       - 1  -   Title 3  - 8,90
4       - 1  -   Title 4  - 8,45
5       - 1  -   Title 5  - 8,11
6       - 1  -   Title 6  - 8,65
```

**when I do the following query it gives me a result like this:**

```php
    public function botdetay($id)
    {
        $id = clean_number($id);
        $this->db->where('kitap_id', $id);
        $this->db->order_by('CAST(bot_fiyat AS DECIMAL(10,2)) ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('botlar');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Result sample table**

```
4,90
8,90
8,20
8,65
8,11
8,45
```

I want to sort the price from the lowest to the most expensive, but I did something wrong. Where's the problem?

Comment: what's the type of column `bot_fiyat`?

Comment: @KrisRoofe I rearranged the table structure.

Comment: I think a `comma` is stopping you from doing sort try to replace a `comma` with `dot`

Comment: What's the type of `bot_fiyat`

Comment: @M.Hemant I changed the problem as a comma point solved thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, Try this way

```
public function botdetay($id)
{
    $id = clean_number($id);
    $this->db->where('kitap_id', $id);
    $this->db->order_by("bot_fiyat", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get('botlar');
    return $query->result();
}
```

it's very helpful for you

Comment: it's very helpful for me.